# How to present a warning message on every screen of an Android app?

Tags: android

I have an Android application with a few screens and I would like to display a message that is always visible if an error condition occurs, and I would like to suppress the display of this message if the error condition goes away.

The "error condition" is if the device fails to transmit new information to the server, and the error condition goes away upon a successful transmission.  The message needs to be crystal clear so that no one can deny having seen it if it was present, no matter what screen the end user was on.

Ideally I am looking for a UI element that can be put up when there is an error, and removed when there is no error, that will be present across all screens and in an ideal situation can be moved by an end user (so the end user can decide where this UI element should be located on the screen), but not suppressed (I don't want anyone suppressing the message and claiming he or she did not see it).

I would naturally prefer to have a single bit of code that creates this UI element and allows it to float in front all screens in the application, but if absolutely necessary I could create code that adds a special error condition UI element that is present across all screens.

Does anyone have any suggestions for a UI element that would meet the bill?

--------------- clarifications -------------------

I suggested (and even implemented a prototype) something that produces notifications when an error occurs and dismisses the toaster notification when the error resolves but that was deemed unacceptable as it did not produce a permanent warning that did not go away until the error condition resolved.  I was told that the issue is the end user may dismiss the notification and then continue doing work and forget he or she dismissed the notification and then complain about the ramifications of the notification (their order never went through because the device was unable to transmit it to the server).

I also suggested producing a warning every single time the device fails to transmit something but that solution was also deemed unacceptable, because the if the user took the device somewhere with no internet he or she would continually have to dismiss the notification, which would be annoying, and is therefore unacceptable.  The notification must be passive (e.g. not require an action by the user to dismiss).

I don't want to shut down the device until the internet comes back - the device can continue to tabulate stuff even without transmitting said stuff to the server.  I just want to make sure there is absolutely no way a remotely intelligent person can say that he or she was unaware their information was not being sent to the server.

It is worth noting that the most common reason the device would fail to communicate with the server is the device has no connection to the internet.  The users take the devices to very remote places with no internet connection so there is no hope for the device to communicate with the server until it returns to someplace that is either less remote or has wireless internet that the device is allowed to use.

Comment: I personally create my own dialog, that will appear if the user gets a bad response from my web calls. I tell them a simplified version of what went wrong and how they can contact our support. If you can automatically retry what ever they were doing for them (to stop them from having to redo things) that would be great.

Comment: I suggested a dialog or a toaster notification but that suggestion was rejected as being to impermanent - the user could dismiss the warning and "forget" that he or she dismissed it and complain about not having seen any indication of an error, which was deemed unacceptable.

Comment: Hmm, I see your problem as I have had the same before. Could you redirect them to a screen and just override onBackPressed, so they are forced to wait? I personally wouldn't do this as I wouldn't like my user to feel trapped. But if you're not allowed to use a temporary solution then this is the only thing that seems fit.

Comment: just set the dialog as not cancelable, and have a button to dismiss it that only gets enabled when your operation finishes successfully. You can have a fragment that displays the dialog that cn be initialised and called from anywhere in the app

Comment: I don't want to shut down the device/app if there is no internet - I just want to put up some kind of notice that the device is tracking and tabulating stuff, but it is not transmitting it anywhere, so no one is going to react to the information being input into the device.

Answer (score 0):

It might not be the most elegant solution, but you can

- have the warning layout included in all your screens; it can be just a `TextView` at the top/bottom of your screen, a small clickable alert `ImageView` in a corner that shows the info in a dialog/toast or something more complicated, depending on your needs
- use a BaseActivity, from which all your activities will extend
- whenever your conditions are met and `onResume` of BaseActivity, show/hide this layout

If it's just about the internet connection, you can also have a `BroadcastReceiver`in the BaseActivity, that will show/hide the warning layout.

Answer (score 0):

I made a toast library that has pre-defined messages for one of my projects. It has error,warnings,wifi warnings etc. I've built it on top of the Toast widget.
[ToastRect github link](https://github.com/bensadiku/ToastRect)

Alternatively, you could build something on top of the dialog fragment which can only be dismissed by the user.